# Terraform Escaping single quotes in single quotes in Double Quotes

Tags: terraform

How does one escape this string where I'm passing a command to postgresql, which contains a single quote string, then the double quotes are escaped because its in a Terraform remote-exec provisioner block?

```
"sudo -u postgres bash -c 'cd $HOME; /usr/pgsql-11/bin/psql -c \"ALTER USER concourse WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD \'supersecretpassword\';\"'",
```

I get the following error.

> Error: Error parsing
>   /Users/user01/Documents/development/Concourse-CI/main.tf: At
>   202:139: illegal char escape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking out the inline SQL statement, and making a file that would be loaded as a template, and then put on the target node using a file provisioner and then calling it later.